# Что делать с промисом и оберткой?

Tags: javascript

Непонятно, как избавиться от замечаний к коду:
на строке 101 Promise.all заворачиваете в промис - это не нужно делать, Promise.all уже возвращает промис;
на строке 151 тоже лишняя обертка из промиса, и еще там же .then древовидно выстроены, а надо плоско.

Кто может помочь?
Код в песочнице - https://repl.it/repls/BothCraftyUsernames

Answer (score 1):

101 строка: Промисы уже получены  от getCurrencyRate(), по этому сразу после PromiseAll можно строить цепочку .then:

```
let convertCurrency = (amount, fromCode, toCode) =>
    Promise.all([getCurrencyRate(fromCode), getCurrencyRate(toCode)])
        .then(result => Math.round(result[1] * amount / result[0]))
        .catch(err => console.error(`\n[Error: ${err}]`));
```

151 строка: Тоже самое getTeg() возвращает промис, с этого места можно строить цепочку .then():

```
let getTagItemsCount = (title) => getTag(title)
            .then(tag => getTagItems(tag.id))
            .then(products => products.length)
            .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Хорошее чтиво по теме:https://habr.com/company/nixsolutions/blog/323066/